# Designing user permissions mechanism

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, permissions, software-design, user-permissions

I have a few types of users who works with the app that helps to optimize processes for public libraries: Client, Librarian, Administrator.

Librarian has restricted access to data in comparison to Administrator. For example Librarian cannot view the Clients from the other library or the other department within the same library.
So that I need to develop permissions logic.

I ask for advice on what are the best practices of designing permissions mechanisms?
What should be done on database level?
What should be done on business logic level?

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for. Isn't user signing into your system. Once he sign in, you know the type of the user and just allow / deny or show hide operations as per user's role.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the sensibility of your data. You could set access rights on database level and use different database logons. But this seems to be to strict for your case... I'd solve this with a common database logon and an application driven rights management.

The command pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is very useful... You can asign one right for each command.

One common way (and there are many more) could look like this... You need following tables:

- User (personal data)
- UserGroup (role data)
- Right (what can be allowed or forbidden, look at "command pattern")
- UserGroup_right (mapping)
- Session (login time and other data connected to the current work)
- SessionRights (Is to be filled on user's login)

A user is member of a user group (= role). You bind the rights to this group.
When a user signs in (into your application) the system knows the user's group membership(s) and collects the connected rights. Any control / menu item within your application reacts automatically (getting invisible or disabled).

Any call to database procedures or functions hands in the session's ID. So database functionality can easily detect wheter a command may be execute, a data list may be returned or not...

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should send different apps to different user types.

An alternative (to above) nice design solution would be to have a single app that could reconfigure its components based on user type.  This would imply loading and discarding assets on demand, according to changing permissions parameters.

If you don't expect a single platform to change user permissions context often, then I would think the first solution would be simpler to execute and more reliable.